# Vue: How to configure Volar's usage of PrettyHtml in VS Code

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, volar, prettyhtml

Specifically, I would like to modify the options.wrapAttributes mentioned here

https://github.com/Prettyhtml/prettyhtml

Do I do this in settings.json? What is the syntax?  I have this so far:

```
"[vue]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "Vue.volar",
},
```

NB. I cannot use html.format.wrapAttributes, because volar is not using vscode-html-languageservice

https://github.com/vuejs/language-tools/issues/812